# A onUploadStart on the Youtube UploadWidget?

Tags: upload, youtube, widget

When we add a video with the YouTube UploadWidget, there is a loader during the upload processing. But when we add a file video, nothing happen ! So the user don't know his file is uploading...

Is there an event like "onUploadStart" to make a loader by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for checking when the uploading process has gone and starting video processing

```
var stack = [];

function onStateChange(event) {
    var state = event.data.state;
    switch (state) {
        case YT.UploadWidgetState.RECORDING:
            break;
        case YT.UploadWidgetState.PENDING:
            break;
        case YT.UploadWidgetState.STOPPED:
            if(stack.pop() == "US")
            {
              //video is uploaded and processing has been started, I show loader here
                stack.push("US");
            }
            stack.push("S");
            break;
    }
}

function onUploadSuccess(event) {
    stack.push("US");
}

function onProcessingComplete(event) {
    if(stack.pop() == "S" && stack.pop() == "US")
    {
        stack = [];
    }
//disable spinner
}
```